# How to detect user rotated the map on IOS 7

Tags: dictionary, ios7, rotation, detect

How do I detect that the user rotated, and dismissed the rotation, on the IOS 7 map? The rotation i mean is the one that pop up a compass on the right corner of the map? (black circle)

Is there any delegate for that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170254/update-map-annotations-on-ios-7-map-camera-rotation.  If you don't need to detect rotation changes _while_ user is rotating, the regionWillChangeAnimated and regionDidChangeAnimated delegate methods should be sufficient.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for your suggestion! These two delegates should work, but for my purposes I think they are too much, i mean, they are raised in every move I make with the device. Is there any other delegate that only fires when the map rotation ends (eg mapDidFinishRotation)?